# Proper setting transaction manager with multitenant databases configuration with spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I have multitenant database in Spring Boot. I store multi spring JDBC templates (based on tomcat Data Sources, configured manually) in map (immutable bean). And I choose proper data source based on uuid in a request (connection pool per database). I have disabled standard configuration in Spring Boot by:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
```

What is the proper way of transaction manager configuration? With single data source I can use PlatformTransactionManager, but how it should be done with multiple jdbc templates/data sources in spring? It would be the best if I could set everything dynamically. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution for using multiple datasources

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

Configure Two DataSources

If you need to configure multiple data sources, you can apply the same tricks that are described in the previous section. You must, however, mark one of the DataSource @Primary as various auto-configurations down the road expect to be able to get one by type.

If you create your own DataSource, the auto-configuration will back off. In the example below, we provide the exact same features set than what the auto-configuration provides on the primary data source

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.foo")
public DataSourceProperties fooDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.foo")
public DataSource fooDataSource() {
    return fooDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.bar")
public BasicDataSource barDataSource() {
    return (BasicDataSource) DataSourceBuilder.create()
            .type(BasicDataSource.class).build();
}
```

fooDataSourceProperties has to be flagged @Primary so that the database initializer feature uses your copy (should you use that).

```
app.datasource.foo.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
app.datasource.foo.maximum-pool-size=30

app.datasource.bar.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
app.datasource.bar.username=dbuser
app.datasource.bar.password=dbpass
app.datasource.bar.max-total=30
```